# libgdx texture region animation wont draw

Tags: java, libgdx

the texture region I am using for my player wont draw to my screen

here is the player class where the player is defined and the texture region is attached to a box 2d body

```
public Player (World world, PlayScreen screen){
super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("player"));
this.world= world;
currentState = State.STANDING;
previousState = State.STANDING;
stateTimer=0;
runningRight=true;
Array<TextureRegion> frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
for(int i=5; i<9; i++){
    frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(),i*50,0,50,50));
}
playerRun= new Animation(0.1f , frames);
defineplayer();
playerStand = new TextureRegion(getTexture(),0,0,50,50);
setBounds(0,0,50,50);
setRegion(playerStand);
}
public void update(float dt){
    setPosition(b2dbody.getPosition().x-getWidth()/2,b2dbody.getPosition ().y-getHeight()/2);
setRegion(getFrame(dt));
}

public TextureRegion getFrame(float dt){
currentState = getState();
TextureRegion region;
switch(currentState){
    case RUNNING:
        region=(TextureRegion) playerRun.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
        break;
    case STANDING:
    default:
        region = playerStand;
        break;
        }
if((b2dbody.getLinearVelocity().x<0 || !runningRight) && !region.isFlipX() ){
    region.flip(true, false);
    runningRight=false;
    }
if((b2dbody.getLinearVelocity().x>0 || runningRight) && region.isFlipX()){
    region.flip(true, false);
    runningRight=true;
    }
stateTimer = currentState == previousState ? stateTimer +dt : 0;
previousState = currentState;
return region;
}
public State getState(){
if(b2dbody.getLinearVelocity().x!=0){
    return State.RUNNING;
    }
else{
    return State.STANDING;
    }   
}
public void defineplayer(){
BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
bdef.position.set(32,32);
bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
b2dbody = world.createBody(bdef);
FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
shape.setRadius(5);

fdef.shape=shape;
b2dbody.createFixture(fdef);
}

}
```

here is the play screen where my player is being displayed and moved

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
private final FinalGame game;
Texture texture;
private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
private Viewport gameport;
private Hud hud; 
private TmxMapLoader loader;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer render;
private Player player;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private Music music;
int Vx;
int Vy;
//Box 2D
private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
public PlayScreen(FinalGame game , String name){
    atlas = new TextureAtlas("Player_And_Enemies.pack");
    hud=new Hud(game.sb, name);
    this.game=game;
    gamecam=new OrthographicCamera();
    gameport=new StretchViewport(FinalGame.width ,FinalGame.height,gamecam);
    loader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map=loader.load("level1.tmx");
    render=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
    gamecam.position.set(gameport.getWorldWidth()/2,gameport.getWorldHeight()/2,0);
    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0),true);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    player=new Player(world,this);
    music = FinalGame.manager.get("Horror field.mp3", Music.class);
    music.setLooping(true);
    music.setVolume(0.1f);
    music.play();

}
@Override
public void show() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public TextureAtlas getAtlas(){
    return atlas;
}

public void handleinput(float dt){
    Vy=0;
    Vx=0;

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
        Vy=40;
        }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
        Vy=-40;
        }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        Vx=40;
        }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        Vx=-40;
        }
    player.b2dbody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(Vx,Vy));
    }
public void update(float dt){
    handleinput(dt);
    world.step(1/60f,6,2);
    player.update(dt);
    gamecam.update();
    render.setView(gamecam);
    }

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //renders the play screen map

    update(delta);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    render.render();

    game.sb.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);
    game.sb.begin();
    player.draw(game.sb);
    game.sb.end();
    game.sb.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);

    //draws all the hud information to the screen
    Hud.stage.draw();

    }

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gameport.update(width, height);

    }

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be great if you improve your question format.

Comment: the picture wont display from the player.draw which uses the super.draw from sprite to render the animation